# Getting the text of the tweet only having tweet id without Elevated access to Twitter developer account

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I tried using tweepy and TwitterAPI but both those solutions do not work because I have Essential access to Twitter developer account and not Elevated (elevated app got rejected).

Basically doing:

- tweepy:

```
# authorization of consumer key and consumer secret

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
  
# set access to user's access key and access secret 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
  
#  calling the api 
api = tweepy.API(auth)
  
# the ID of the status
id = 1272771459249844224
  
# fetching the status
status = api.get_status(id)
  
#  fetching the text attribute

text = status.text
```

- Twitter API:

```
r = api.request('statuses/show/:%d' % 210462857140252672)

print(r.text)
```

Both of those solutions do not work. I think all the solutions that include access keys stuff will not work.

I also tried some web scraping but it also does not work. This is what I tried:

```
from lxml import html

import requests

page = requests.get('https://twitter.com/UniteAlbertans/status/572342978255048705')

print(page.text)

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

tree.xpath('//span[@class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"]/text()')
```

But I do not think that works because when I print the page text I do not even see the text of the tweet.

Could someone help me how I could get the text of the tweet given tweet ID through code?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: please try editing the question again using the same python syntax (plain text) you use in your actual code. those lines `//` is invalid python syntax

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken done

Comment: running your tweepy code I use `print(status.text)` and get `Which movie did you watch recently?

Reply us!
.
.
.
.
.
#tuesdaymood #TuesdayThoughts #Bollywood #Hollywood #genre
#movies #movie #fun`      <--  is this the expected output?

Comment: I dont have access to Twitter Developer Elevated account, I only have essential access. I get an error saying:
TweepError: [{'message': 'You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve', 'code': 453}]. I applied for Elevated access but it got rejected :(
Yes, it's the expected output

Comment: Hmm, ok, i've no idea about that, seems this may not be a coding question, but more of a Twitter Developer account question...

Comment: I am more asking about other ways to potentially accomplish the same thing. Is there maybe some web scraping technique I could use to get the tweet text? (it cannot include access keys)

Comment: With twitter currently blocking automated requests seems it's not currently possible without using access keys, etc. but hopefully someone here can provide an alternative...

Comment: twiter may use JavaScript to add elements to HTML but `requests`, `lxml`, `beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. it may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. But some servers may have methods to detect `Selenium` and also block it.

Answer (score 0):

This works using Tweepy and the v2 Twitter API (documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweet-lookup)):

```
Client.get_tweet(id)
```

Comment: this also doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67978717/tweepy-3-10-0-attributeerror-module-tweepy-has-no-attribute-client

Comment: Are you using version 4 of Tweepy (which has full support for v2 of the Twitter API)? Have you initialised the Client object?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Essential Access, then you can just use the Tweepy Twitter API v2 methods. So generally, you can't access `tweepy.API`, instead you have to find a way with `tweepy.Client`.

To get the text of a tweet by tweet id, try:

```
import tweepy

# token for twitter developers
client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token="<bearer_token>",
    consumer_key="<consumer_key>",
    consumer_secret="<consumer_secret>",
    access_token="<access_token>",
    access_token_secret="<access_token_secret>",
)

# find tweet by id
tweet = client.get_tweet(id=<tweet_id_here>)

# extract data from tweet
text = tweet.data
print(text)
```

Be sure, that you have installed the latest version of tweepy. In my case i had tweepy version 4.4.0.