# What's the meaning of this error messaging trying to use Twitter API Bearer Token with Tweepy on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tweepy, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to access the Twitter API via Tweepy on Google Colab, and am following the Tweepy documentation on the Twitter APIv2.
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/authentication.html#twitter-api-v2

So this is what I'm running:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client("my_bearer_token")
```

With my actual Bearer Token inserted.

However, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2d6a240a3613> in <module>()
      1 import tweepy
      2 
----> 3 client = tweepy.Client("my_bearer_token")

AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'Client'
```

I've read this post on the issue,
[Tweepy 3.10.0, AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'Client'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67978717/tweepy-3-10-0-attributeerror-module-tweepy-has-no-attribute-client)
but I'm still not clear why the Tweepy documented code wouldn't work.

If Tweepy has no attribute 'Client', is there an update for that attribute?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67981138/17991769

Comment: Thanks @Carst3n. I did see that link, but figured it was dated because the Tweepy documentation now states that v4.5 is the latest.
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.5.0/install.html

And those are the install steps I followed. So I should have a v4+ version installed.

Answer (score 2):

if you do tweepy.**version** , you'll see that colab actually has tweepy 3.10.0 installed. Faced this problem myself

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).