# How to retrieve large data from tweepy Twitter API to python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

I want to retrieve data based on certain keyword from Twitter API using tweepy to pandas python. I already have elevated developer account that can retrieve up to 2mio data/month per project based on [this official documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products). I also already can get the twitter data with this code. But, I want to retrieve more data (at least 100k tweet, regardless it's in 1 time execution or may be up to 10x execution. But, no matter the number I input at the `max_result` parameter, there are only about 50 data I can get.

So, is anyone know how is the solution? I already try pagination like [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-access-data-from-the-twitter-api-using-tweepy-python-e2d9e4d54978) but got an error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67978717/tweepy-3-10-0-attributeerror-module-tweepy-has-no-attribute-client) that say if the feature is still on development

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('my api key', 'my api key secret')
auth.set_access_token('my access token', 'my access token secret')
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# get tweet based on certain keywords
KEYWORDS = 'flower OR doll'
tweets = api.search(KEYWORDS, result_type="mixed", tweet_mode="extended", max_results = 10000)

columns = ['time', 'user', 'tweet']
data = []

for tweet in tweets:
  data.append([tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.full_text])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
```